# Scraping a web site for images that's AJAX intensive

Tags: ajax, vb.net, web-scraping, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

I am new to the Scraping scene and would like some help in getting information on how to go about getting all the images with a certain class name from the web page.

The problem being is that its all built with AJAX and it only loads more images as you scrolling downward. Naturally loading up the website with the Webbrowser control only loads the default number of images before you start scrolling down.

Luckily I can get the total amount of images that will be on that page for any particular category.

How would I go about getting ALL the images before starting to run the htmlagilitypack command to snatch all images with a certain class name?

It loads about 30 images at the beginning then, depending on what category you choose, it can consist of a total of 800 images more or less. As you scroll closer to the bottom it loads up another 30 images.

So are there any tricks to automating this process and knowing when its reached the bottom of all images loaded?

My code so far getting the 30 images default on the page is this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()

    htmlCode = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml        
    doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode)

    Dim totalNumOfPosters() As String = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='main-title-divider']").InnerText.Split(" ")

    Debug.WriteLine(totalNumOfPosters(0)) 'Shows total num of images

    For Each img As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[contains(@class,'img-poster')]")
        posterArray.Add(img.Attributes("src").Value.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

I just need someone that has done something like this before to let me know the best way to approach getting the rest of the images!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

General idea is,use your web developer tool (Firebug or google developer tool depends which browser you are using ) to figure out how the site sends the Ajax request.

For firefox, go to the page you want, F12,navigate to Net tab then XHR
   sub-tab.

Clear the firebug xhr tab  first.

scroll the web page.

Back to firebug panel, you will get the request info.

Expand the + .

Go to the post tab then you will be able to see the post parameters.

Send the request from your client with the parameters.

But if the website requires login to see the content, then its another story because of the same-origin policy.

Comment: Cant find the + for the POST. See OP for an image.

Comment: Try to use Firebug.